# When to use KNN and when Naive Bayes algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, k-nearest-neighbour

Trying to get clear guidelines on when we should use KNN and when Naive Bayes but not getting anything.

The indication I am getting is KNN is a lazy learner and NB is used to spam/ham classification of emails..

However I wanted to know the selection rationale based on :
1)  Data types(like categorical, ordinal, continues or mixed etc.) 
2)  High/Low number of columns
3)  Type of problem
4)  Any Colinearity or Any thing else.

Comment: The primary difference is that KNN is [unsupervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) and NB is [supervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)

Comment: @Scott, as per my understanding KNN is also supervised (though lazy learner) but please explain you rationale of calling KNN unsupervised..

Comment: supervision == we have measurements of the thing we're trying to predict.  KNN is for clustering when we don't have measurements of the clusters.  NB is for "classification" which is basically clustering but when we *do* have measurements of the clusters (e.g. spam v ham)

Comment: @Scott KNN is surely a supervised algorithm. Each sample is assigned to a value (class) considering the labels of its N closest neighbours. I think you mistake KNN with K-Means which is a clustering technique.

Comment: I have done just that.  I concede.